# Router Blocking One Specific Site; IP resolves, but Times Out

Tags: networking, router, timeout

I have a [Linksys WRT54GL Wi-Fi Wireless-G Broadband Router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BTL0OA) in use.
For whatever reason, for the past couple of days I have been unable to access a single web site, http://basecamp.com, through the router. If I plug directly into my modem I have no issue.
When I attempt to `ping basecamp.com` I get the IP address resolved (204.62.11.180), but the ping requests all time out. Running `tracert` (either directly from the router or via Command Prompt [Windows 8]) yields the following:

```
Tracing route to basecamp.com [204.62.114.180]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    39 ms    26 ms    14 ms  cpe-71-66-96-1.neo.res.rr.com [71.66.96.1]
  3     9 ms    10 ms    11 ms  tge7-1.kentoh0903h.midwest.rr.com [24.164.109.246]
  4    16 ms    15 ms    12 ms  cpe-24-33-106-10.cinci.res.rr.com [24.33.106.10]
  5    12 ms    18 ms    15 ms  24.33.103.54
  6    19 ms    18 ms    18 ms  be29.clmkohpe01r.midwest.rr.com [65.29.1.212]
  7    28 ms    30 ms    26 ms  bu-ether25.chctilwc00w-bcr00.tbone.rr.com [107.14.19.16]
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 [it continues like this indefinitely]
```

So something appears to be getting lost in that routing? I figure I can solve this problem by factory-resetting the router (which I've had to do a few times as of late when it just loses Internet entirely, while LAN still functions). Is the router simply on its way out? It's many years old at this point. I would, however, like to know why this is happening, and less so how to fix (I don't want to factory-reset if I can avoid it).

EDIT: My resolution was cloning my PC's MAC address (see Bilo's answer below), but wanted to add more for those coming in here later: I had an email conversation with Basecamp, and confirmed that my router's IP address was *not* banned. They also mentioned that over the past week they've been seeing the occasional odd case of wonky routing from Time Warner (my ISP), so it looks to be an ISP-related issue.

Comment: Can u access via http://204.62.114.180 ?

Comment: Could be a problem with rr's network routing. Is RoadRunner your ISP? If so you should call them.

Comment: @DavidPostill Is it an ISP issue though? As I said, when I connect directly from PC to the modem I can resolve the web site just fine. It's only when going through the router that the problem eixsts.

Comment: @Bilo No, both the domain and the IP address time out in the same manner.

Comment: What about if you clone the mac address from your PC?

Comment: @Bilo could you elaborate on that? I think I saw something about MAC cloning in the router's settings, but am not sure what its function would be.

Comment: You can check the mac-address by this way (Windows): http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-MAC-Address-of-Your-Computer
Then enter it on the router's settings, it depends on model, you may need to enter in XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX format or XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX or just XXXXXXXXXXXX, try different way to enter if it prompt you for invalid value

Comment: @Bilo I know how to get my MAC address, but what I meant was: What purpose/function does cloning a MAC address have?

Comment: As you said you can't access a single specified website `basecamp.com`, it may be banned your IP for some reason, if you clone the mac address from the PC, you can get the same IP on the Linksys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25868/discussion-between-scott-and-bilo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can't access a single specified website `basecamp.com`, it may be IP ban problem, you can try to clone the mac address from the PC to Linksys in order to obtain the same IP address for testing.

Comment: Indeed, cloning my PC's MAC address to the router (which gives a different external IP address, which is something I learned today) lets me access the site again.